# SQL Server: Create a duplicate of a database without the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, toad

I have a database called AQOA_Core with huge amount of data.
I have a newly created database called AQOA_Core1 which is basically empty. I want to write a query to duplicate AQOA_Core to AQOA_Core1 without the data. I guess to be precise I want to create a skeleton of the primary database into the secondary database.
PS: I use Toad for my database operations.

Comment: SQL Delta is the best tool to compare Different Database structure and syncronize two instances

Comment: If you were using SQL Server Management Studio, you could right click on the database and choose "Script Database as --> Create", which would generate the script you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQL Server Script Wizard](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-script-database-by-sql-2008-script-wizard.aspx) for scripting database objects. You can exclude data, and select the database object types you want to include in your script

Please check the SQL Server guide I referenced above,
I hope it helps you